# How to pass in image to C++ executable and store output image in a new directory?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, image, executable

I'm trying to write a program in python wrapper for a C++ executable. The executable takes in an image and returns an edited image. I've looked into using subprocess.run, in this way:

```
output_img = subprocess.run(["executable","argument"], shell=True)
```

However, this gives me the error of "executable: command not found." Also, the executable file does not have .exe at the end, and I'm not sure why because it was given to me by someone else.

I simply want to run an image through this executable and take the output image and store it into a new folder. Any ideas how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: "the executable file does not have .exe at the end" - whether or not that matters is OS specific.

Answer (score 0):

First try and run it yourself in Terminal. So, to find out if it is a suitable binary to run on your system, run:

```
file executable
```

and click `edit` under your question and paste the output. Then make sure the executable bit is set with:

```
chmod +x executable
```

Then try and run it (if you trust it) with:

```
./executable someImage.jpg
```

Then see the most recently created file in your directory to see what it output - it will be the last one listed if you run:

```
ls -lrt
```

If that all works, change your Python to:

```
output_img = subprocess.run(["./executable","argument"], shell=True)
```